# Install ip package on router with OpenWRT

Tags: networking, router, openwrt, iproute

I am using a Linkys WRT54G v3 router with OpenWRT v10.03.1. My end goal is to use Traffic Control (`tc`) and Network Emulator (`netem`) on the router, which are in the `ip` package (this is the `iproute2` package in most linux distributions).

However, my computer is connected to a work network, and the router is connected to my computer via an ethernet cable. I am not able to connect the router to the internet, wired or wireless, because of work restrictions. I have to access the internet through my computer, and then `ssh` into the router via `PuTTy`.

Is there any way to download the `ip` package on my computer and push it onto the router? Can you direct me to a safe place to download the `ip` package, if such exists?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of just down voting my question, could you provide some insight to why it is not a good question, if it is not one? Or could you give me some constructive criticism on how I could improve it?

Comment: install package offline is not recommended, i have ever try it and missing dependency be next problem, that was my experience using tpl mr3420, if you want to continue your works do your router have any ports to mount those files, or maybe you can store package files and put on your local file server and wget from your router using ssh

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the down arrow, you will see the reasons for a down vote. It is different for questions and answers. The [help] offers guidance on how to ask a better question, and what is, or is not, on-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so your router is not connecting to the internet.And you want to download the ip package to your PC then install it into your router right ?

1.For Linkys WRT54G v3 with OpenWRT v10.03.1.Here is the link:

https://downloads.openwrt.org/backfire/10.03.1/brcm-2.4/packages/ip_2.6.29-1-2_brcm-2.4.ipk

You might need to install dependencies as well.

2.If your PC is Windows OS ,you can use *WinSCP* to copy the package into your router.
Or if your PC is Linux OS,you can use *scp* command.

After copying the package,install it by opkg

```
opkg -i <package>
```

Comment: Okay, actually it says "Packages were found, but none compatible with the architectures configured." Does that mean that I need to install other dependencies, or that the `ip` package just won't work with this router?

Comment: I figured it out. I had to change a little bit of `/etc/opkg.conf` or use a different version of the `ip` package. Thanks for the help